# Given that "arguments" is not a true array, why does Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) work, but Array.prototype.slice.call(someobject) not work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If the *arguments* is just an object with a length property, then why does it seem to behave differently from other non-array objects with respect to, say, Array.prototype.slice.

For example, the following code first alerts "undefined", and then alerts "foo". Why do these differ?

```
(function(a){
  var myobj = {0 : "foo"};
  var myobjarray = Array.prototype.slice.call(myobj);
  var argumentsarray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  alert(myobjarray.shift());
  alert(argumentsarray.shift());
})("foo");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works if your object has a `length` property.

```
var myobj = { 0: "foo", 1: "bar", length: 2 };
var myobjarray = [].slice.call(myobj);
alert(myobjarray.shift());
```

Most Array methods rely on the length property.  If you try to execute an Array method on an object that doesn't expose the expected interface, you'll get unexpected results.